# How to update Stripe subscription quantity? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to update the quantity of a Stripe subscription that has already been created. But I keep getting this error:

```
"error": {
    "message": "Invalid array",
    "param": "items",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
```

I am first retrieving the Stripe subscription, updating the value, and then posting the updated value. Here is the code:

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
  stripe_sub_id
);

subscription.items.data[0].quantity = newCount;

stripe.subscriptions.update(
    stripe_sub_id,
    {items: { data: subscription.items.data }}
)
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I update the value of "quantity" within the items.data array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really just mutate `items.data` and pass it directly due to the way the Stripe API works(the format of items returned in a retrieve call is not the same as format of the parameters when POSTing, they're different).

So you need to actually write some more custom code/business logic to explicitly create the params object for the change you want. Something like this maybe.

```
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.retrieve(
  stripe_sub_id
);

let IdOfPriceToUpdate = "price_xxx";
let newQuantity = 5;

let updatedItemParams = subscription.items.data.
    filter(item => item.price != IdOfPriceToUpdate). // find what to change
    map(item => {return { id:item.id, quantity:newQuantity}}) // change it

await stripe.subscriptions.update(
    stripe_sub_id,
    {items: updatedItemParams}
)
```

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/upgrade-downgrade#changing

Comment: Interesting!  So I was on the right track...your answer also removes the additional layer of nesting (under `data`.)  But you're also only setting the ID and the updated quantity field on the inputs.  TIL!

Comment: BTW there's no reason (and maybe semantically better) that all your `let` could not be `const` in the answer.  And where does `IdOfPriceToUpdate` come from?  And should the `filter` be `item.price.id !== IdOfPriceToUpdate`?

Comment: @MattMorgan `IdOfPriceToUpdate` is just a placeholder, since you probably call this kind of code from business logic where you are have the Stripe Price ID that you want to increase the quantity of and would pass it in. And sure I could have used `const` and double equals, it was just a quick snippet though!

Comment: Also note that what I'm returning in the `map` here is the shape of https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update?lang=node#update_subscription-items , i.e. it has to look like object there (the ID is the subscription item ID `si_xxx`). The code is to find the SubscriptionItem that uses the Price you're looking for, and then update that item to have the `quantity` you want(this is how this is done in Stripe, but this specific part of the API is very tricky to understand).

Comment: Thank you. This saved me so much time. I just like to add based on `items.data` that I was working with the `filter` had to be `.filter(item => item.price.id === IdOfPriceToUpdate)` for it to work. Because `item.price` is an object that has `id` and I had to match an item with a price object that its `id` matches with the `price_id` that I wanted to update.